# Handling orders with Multi Vendor Marketplace

Tags: database, database-design, e-commerce

My plan is that on my multi vendor ecommerce site, the orders will be fulfilled by vendors themselves. However I don't want my site users to be frustrated with placing 2 orders for 2 products from same/different vendors. I would like to provide them the add to cart option and do the checkout only once.

My skills of database design is not up to the mark and i am lost as to how should i handle this case in my database. I have two tables right now

**Order**

```
 Schema::create('order', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('order_number');
            $table->integer('customer_id');
            $table->integer('order_status'); // Does not make sense as if order has products from multiple vendors. There will be different status from each vendor
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Order Detail**

```
Schema::create('order_detail', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('vendor_id')->unsigned();
        $table->tinyInteger('quantity')->unsiged();
        $table->string('sku');
        $table->integer('order_status_code');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

So, If customer purchase multiple items in a single order. Each item will have its row in `order_detail` table linked with its `vendor_id`. Lets say one vendor processed the order while other is pending. How can i reflect this is main `order` table ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also wondering about this issue..
I think you should create 2 tables for orders. 
One for customers and one for vendors..
orders_vendors would reference to orders_customers..
Whenever a vendor processes the order you check if all of the other vendor processed as well
If they did , you process customers_order

Answer (score 4):

You need to split your database into more tables. Think about what each table needs to know.

You create an order that will be placed on your marketplace website. This order would contain information connected to the customer and possibly a total. Creating a separate order, or 'invoice' that you then send to your vendors would contain only the items that pertain to that vendor. Vendors need no knowledge of the order or invoices placed to other vendors. They only need to know about the items they need to fulfill and the money they will be paid.

The invoice can be connected to the items and unit items as well as shipments, in case the items will be shipped in separate boxes. Basically you look at what something needs to know. A warehouse only needs to know what items to ship, where to ship them too and when to ship it. They shouldn't have any knowledge of payment details. Store owners will need to know how much money they are making but don't need to know about shipments. If they happen to be the same person, they will get both pieces of information but it won't be in the same place.

When creating your objects from the database, you first load the order. Then you load the invoice objects into an array that belong to that order. Each invoice will contain a shipments object array that contain the actual item objects array being purchased.

```
--ORDERS TABLE--
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID | Customer ID | Shipping ID | Billing ID | Number | Created | Updated | Checkout | Payment | Token | Currency | Local | Invoices Total | Adj_Total | Total

--INVOICES TABLE--
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID | Order ID | Vendor ID | Number | Issued | Items Total | Adj_Total | Total | Coupon ID | Notes | State | Fulfilled

--ITEMS TABLE--
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID | Invoice ID | Variant ID | Product ID | Quantity | Unit Price | Unit Total | Adj_Total | Total  | Product Name | Variant Name

--UNITS TABLE--
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID | Item ID | Shipment ID | Adj_Total | Created | Updated
```

You still need to write coding logic that shows the customer 1 order at checkout. They also need to see the separate shipments if you are going to charge shipping separately for each shipment in case they will be allowed to select different methods for each shipment, for example UPS or Fedex.

> Disclaimer:
>
> I am putting together an open source multi-vendor database
>   design that might be of interest to you. It's too large to post here
>   but you can find it on Reddit. Please feel free to visit and share
>   your thoughts and opinions to further improve this design for others.
>
> https://www.reddit.com/r/Database/comments/f1d4fx/marketplace_database_design/

Answer (score 1):

for the customer its a single order. for the vendors they will have to get an 'order' that is specifically for the products they are going to fulfill. that means shipping (and tax) has to be calculated per line item in the order. there isn't any other way to do it because you have to pay your vendors separately. so the main order is going to reference the vendor orders. tracking the shipping fulfillment should be part of the vendors order, because you will need to monitor how fast and how well your different vendors are completing the orders.

definitely check out amazon - do a single order from different merchants who will fulfill the order -- in other words not fulfilled by amazon or prime -- and see how amazon shows it to you as a customer both in the order process and in the follow up. next sign up to be a seller on amazon and review all the docs.